# How to read only specific, needed values from a csv file into python with genfromtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a python newbie. I have a lot of data (25000 csv files) which I need to work with. I am importing the files and doing some statistical stuff with (means, standard deviations, plots). One file contains of 480x640 (temperature-)values. I don't need the correct order the values, so I don't care about the column or row order. Some files have 9 rows header and some 17. I run the following code:

```
data = glob.glob('*.csv')
variance_data = []

for one_file in all_files:
try:
    with open(one_file) as data:
        all_data = np.genfromtxt((line.replace(',','.') for line in data),skip_header=9,delimiter=";")
except ValueError: 
    with open(one_file) as data:
        all_data = np.genfromtxt((line.replace(',','.') for line in data),skip_header=17,delimiter=";")

variance_data.append(np.nanvar(all_data))
```

This reads most of the data well. But I need to exclude all values from all files which are under -10 (so I only need temperatures above -10 degree Celsius). How can I deal with this? I guess there's an easy way which I still don't know. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? It converts any entry in your array which is below -10 to `nan`.

```
# Create some sample data
all_data = 20 * np.random.randn(480,640)

all_data[all_data <= -10] = np.nan
variance_data.append(np.nanvar(all_data))
```

Note: Your sample code below the `for` loop all needs indenting.

Comment: thanks very much. yes, of course it's intended, I just wasn't that familiar with posting here :) your code seems to work, I use it after my for loop. But it seems to give me the same results as before. I will take a further look.

Comment: If you do `print np.nanvar(all_data)` before and after the assignment, you should see the value change.

Comment: That is great news, and a successful first question and answer! Don't forget to accept the answer.